# New to java, need assistance

Tags: java

I am trying to make a endless loop pig Latin translator until the user enters a "q" to quit the program. I am having issues finalizing the while statement. The error that I am getting is as followed.

> PigLatin.java:27: error: cannot find symbol    } while (word != "q");
>               ^   symbol:   variable word   location: class PigLatin

Here is my source code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PigLatin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the pig latin convertor.");
        do {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String word, pig;
            char first;

            System.out.print("enter word or press 'q' to quit: ");
            word = in.next();
            word = word.toLowerCase();
            System.out.println(word);

            first = word.charAt(0);
            if (first == 'a' ||  first == 'e' || first == 'i' || 
                first == 'o' || first == 'u')  // vowel
                pig = word + "way";      
            else
                pig = word.substring(1) + word.charAt(0) + "ay";
            System.out.println("pig-latin version: " + pig);
        } while (word != "q");
    }
}
```

Comment: Its `while (!word.equals("q"));` and declare `word` outside of your loop.

Comment: `word` needs to be declared outside of the loop, also follow @Satya advise about comparing Strings

Comment: Thanks for the simple fix of the loop. Now I cant seem to get the program to stop once the user has input "q". Using: while (!word.equals('Q'))

Comment: Use double quotes and check your case.

Comment: [compare-strings-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `word` has been declared in the wrong place, ie. within the `do..while` loop, rather than before. This is causing the compilation error.

Once you fix that, you still have a bug because `String` comparisons should use `equals()` not `!=` (or `==`).

Try something like:

```
String word;
do {
    ...
} while (!word.equals("q"));
```

You could also use `word.equalsIgnoreCase("q")` if you don't care whether they enter `"q"` or `"Q"`.

Comment: Well that fixed the program for stopping the loop now its adding ay to it (enter word or press Q to quit: 
q
pig-latin version: qay)... maybe the program is to good :) haha i kid Thanks so much for your help this is what I was looking for.